# Change color of the part of the plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

What is the fastest option for changing the color of the part of the plot. Say I have data with 1000000 points and I want to quickly change first 1000 from blue to red.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate the parts of the plot, which take the same color, for e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a= np.arange(0,10)
b=np.arange(10,20)

plt.plot(c[0:5], d[0:5], color='red')
plt.plot(c[4:10], d[4:10], color='blue')
```